# Ubuntu 13.04 will not boot from Live CD

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, windows-8, radeon, hp-pavilion

When I try to boot up Ubuntu 13.04 from a live cd be I send to the normal boot (Windows 8 )

This is what I got after I run the repair-boot dvd: http://paste2.org/cj0K8pbF

I have a HP Pavilion dv6-2153eo PC

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your BIOS is made to boot to a CD first.  If it's UEFI instead of BIOS, make sure you have downloaded the 64-bit version.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I can boot ubuntu 12.04 from a live cd, and I have downloaded 64 bit

Comment: My boot order is 1.notebook hard drive. 2.internal CD/DVD ROM Drive. 3.Usb diskette on key/USB hard disk. 4. USB CD/DVD rom drive. 5.! USB Floppy. 6.!network adapter

Comment: change it to 1. internal CD/DVD ROM (2. - 4. anything else) and make sure your live installation DVD is in the internal drive.

Comment: I change boot order 1. To internal CD/DVD ROM, but when I startup my PC comes I to a windows 8 recover menu

Comment: What program did you use to make the live DVD?  You can't just copy and paste the files on the DVD.  Also, do an MD5 hash check (I think Ubuntu supports that) to check if your Ubuntu ISO is corrupted or not.

Comment: I have burn the iso file on DVD with poweriso

Comment: http://paste2.org/cj0K8pbF

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I had followed all the instructions and tips (including ensuring and testing with the Windows Install disc that the DVD was boot drive).

I was finally able to boot from DVD and install Ubuntu by:

Booting into Windows
Inserting the Ubuntu Install DVD
Going to the Ubuntu install DVD in Windows File Explorer
Double click the wubi.exe file

When the program is started it will display a radio button with an option to reboot now.  I selected it and everything worked.  I am not sure how this was different than a normal reboot but I was able to boot from the DVD and install Ubuntu.  If this does not work there is a third radio button option that offers additional help.

Also, [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) page may help.  I went though it and nothing worked for me but they are good suggestions.

Comment: This is what I got after I run the boot repair dvd: http://paste2.org/cj0K8pbF